# Iterate through a numpy ndarray, manage first and last elements

Tags: python, numpy, compare

I have a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 4, 25, 26])
```

I would like to iterate over this list to produce pairs of "matching" elements. In the above array, 7 matches 7. You only compare the element "ahead" and the element "behind".

My problem: how do I deal with the first and last elements?

This is what I have to begin with:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]):
    print( "Match at entry %d at array location (%d)" % (arr[i], i))
else:
    pass
```

This outputs:

```
Match at entry 7 at array location (3)
Match at entry 7 at array location (4)
Match at entry 4 at array location (6)
Match at entry 1 at array location (9)
Match at entry 9 at array location (11)
Match at entry 9 at array location (12)
```

I feel the condition should be

```
 if ((arr[i] == arr[i+1]) and (arr[i] == arr[i-1]))
```

but this throws an error.

How do I deal with the first and last elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid loops in NumPy.

Using slightly modified array with pairs at the start end:

```
>>> arr = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 4, 25, 26, 26])
```

This finds the first index of each pair.

```
>>> np.where(arr[:-1] == arr[1:])[0]
array([ 0,  4,  6,  9, 11, 12, 16])
```

Printing them out:

```
arr = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 4, 25, 26, 26])
matches = np.where(arr[:-1] == arr[1:])[0] 
for index in matches:
    for i in [index, index + 1]:
        print("Match at entry %d at array location (%d)" % (arr[i], i))
```

prints:

```
Match at entry 2 at array location (0)
Match at entry 2 at array location (1)
Match at entry 7 at array location (4)
Match at entry 7 at array location (5)
Match at entry 4 at array location (6)
Match at entry 4 at array location (7)
Match at entry 1 at array location (9)
Match at entry 1 at array location (10)
Match at entry 9 at array location (11)
Match at entry 9 at array location (12)
Match at entry 9 at array location (12)
Match at entry 9 at array location (13)
Match at entry 26 at array location (16)
Match at entry 26 at array location (17)
```

The function `np.where` can be used in several ways. In our case we use the condition `arr[:-1] == arr[1:]`. This compares each element with the next in the array:

```
>>> arr[:-1] == arr[1:]
array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Now applying `np.where` to this condition gives a tuple with matching indices.

```
>>> cond = arr[:-1] == arr[1:]
>>> np.where(cond)
(array([ 0,  4,  6,  9, 11, 12, 16]),)
```

Since we have a 1D array, we get a tuple with one element. For a 2D array we would have gotten a tuple with two elements, holding the indices along the first and second dimension. We take these indices out of the tuple:

```
>>> np.where(cond)[0]
array([ 0,  4,  6,  9, 11, 12, 16])
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help. I should mention that your definition of `arr` is not the same as mine.

Comment: This intentional to show the effect for the first and last element.